# Root of non linear equation (Python)

Tags: python, optimization, solver

I am trying to get the root of a function and have been recommended to try using the Newthon Method.

I have tried to do the following:

```
def newton(f,Df,x0,epsilon,max_iter):
    '''Approximate solution of f(x)=0 by Newton's method.

    Parameters
    ----------
    f : function
        Function for which we are searching for a solution f(x)=0.
    Df : function
        Derivative of f(x).
    x0 : number
        Initial guess for a solution f(x)=0.
    epsilon : number
        Stopping criteria is abs(f(x)) < epsilon.
    max_iter : integer
        Maximum number of iterations of Newton's method.

    Returns
    -------
    xn : number
        Implement Newton's method: compute the linear approximation
        of f(x) at xn and find x intercept by the formula
            x = xn - f(xn)/Df(xn)
        Continue until abs(f(xn)) < epsilon and return xn.
        If Df(xn) == 0, return None. If the number of iterations
        exceeds max_iter, then return None.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> f = lambda x: x**2 - x - 1
    >>> Df = lambda x: 2*x - 1
    >>> newton(f,Df,1,1e-8,10)
    Found solution after 5 iterations.
    1.618033988749989
    '''
    xn = x0
    for n in range(0,max_iter):
        fxn = f(xn)
        if abs(fxn) < epsilon:
            print('Found solution after',n,'iterations.')
            return xn
        Dfxn = Df(xn)
        if Dfxn == 0:
            print('Zero derivative. No solution found.')
            return None
        xn = xn - fxn/Dfxn
    print('Exceeded maximum iterations. No solution found.')
    return None

f = lambda x: 1.03078 - (((x + 1.08804)**(23/252))*((2*x + 1.08804)**(37/252))*((3*x + 1.08804)**(19/126)))
```

But I need Df to be the first derivative of f. I have tried using scipy and simpy to get that but it is a different data type so that way the function I am using does not work.

If not by doing this way, could anyone recommend a different method?

Thanks

Comment: You could approximate the derivative: `Df = lambda x, dx=1e-6: (f(x) - f(x + df)) / df`

Comment: Have you searched SO for other Q&A's regarding Newton's Method for finding roots to compare what you have implemented to what others have implemented?

Comment: Thanks, but what is df?

Comment: Yes wwii, but I still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @ForceBru:  Df = lambda x, dx=1e-6: (f(x) - f(x + **dx**)) / **dx** ?

Comment: @wwii, yes, I typo'd, thanks

Comment: @Gustavo, it was supposed to be `dx`, see comments above

Comment: Once you get the derivative in sympy, you can use the lambdify function to get a callable python function.

Comment: As if it needed saying... One of the requirements of Newton's Method is the first derivative.  You could supply that from an analytic approach and put it in a second function or you could approximate it as noted in other comments.  If that isn't viable, there are other methods such as Bisection.  Both have goods&others.  Newton may not converge.  Bisection requires starting points that straddle a prospective root, but it is guaranteed to converge.  And if the f you are working with is the one in the lambda in your code, you could express that analytically...  just chain rule that sucker out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of an analytic way to calculate the derivative, but i think an approximation would not change the result of your function. Try to replace
Dfxn = Df(xn)
with
Dfxn = (f(xn+delta)-f(xn))/delta
for some small delta. Depends on nature of your function, but I'd say anything less than .1 should be fine?